# How to convert adp to accdb or mdp using Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, adp

I have an access database that is saved as a ADP file and I need to convert it to an ACCDB or MDB file format.
The problem is that there are 7 tables (saved as dbo) that are coming from a SQL server 2008 backend.

Is there any way to convert this database into the desired format (.ACCDB or .MDB) seamlessly?

Comment: You can't do it seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

seamlessly no, but this should get you started:

[Steps to convert an old adp file to accdb](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cba21b60-0235-433b-9157-7e055e2e4b41/how-steps-for-convert-an-old-adp-file-to-accdb-in-access-20102013?forum=accessdev)